# Set a custom requirements.txt for a Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

I have several functions in **the same `main.py` of a unique repo**, each of them being deployed on GCP Cloud Function like that:

- `gcloud functions deploy func1 --entry-point=my_function_1`
- `gcloud functions deploy func2 --entry-point=my_function_2`
- ...

I have a common `requirements.txt`. Everything works fine, except **one of my functions needs a specific dependency which is extremely slow to install** (a huge AI-related module). It make all the deployments very slow, since they all share the same `requirements.txt`.

**Is it possible to specify a requirement file for just one Cloud Function inside a repo?** Or do you know any workaround (like a way to specify a list of modules to install) that could allow me to custom the requirements of this specific function without affecting the others?

I tried to look at the [doc for specifying dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python), but it looks like each solution they give is at the repo scale, and not at the function scale.

It would be very painful to have a different repo just for solving this. Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: You will need to have a separate python project for each function that doesn't share the same requirements, but they don't have to be in their own repo.

Comment: @DougStevenson What is a separate python project? You mean a separate folder with its own main and requirements, and set this folder path with the --source param of `gcloud functions deploy` ?

Comment: Yes, unless you have another way of specifying a different requirements that doesn't necessarily have anything to do with CF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, you can delegate this responsability to the CI CD part, example :

**The project structure :**

[image]

- A `functions` folder contains all the Cloud Functions and each of them is put in a separate folder `saving_job_failures_bq` and `saving_job_failures_bq_other`
- Each Cloud Function contains the `main.py` file and the associated `requirements.txt` file

Then you can deploy each Cloud Function separately with a `gcloud` command from the same project and `Github` repository :

**Deploy `saving_job_failures_bq` Function with its `requirements.txt` file, this command is executed at the root of the project and repo :**

```bash
gcloud functions deploy saving-job-failures-bq \
  --gen2 \
  --region=europe-west1 \
  --runtime=python310 \
  --source=functions/saving_job_failures_bq \
  --entry-point=save_gcs_file_to_bq_function \
  --run-service-account=your-sa-email \
  --trigger-event-filters="type=google.cloud.storage.object.v1.finalized" \
  --trigger-event-filters="bucket=event-arc-trigger-function" \
  --trigger-location=europe-west1 \
  --trigger-service-account=your-sa-trigger-email
```

**Deploy `saving_job_failures_bq_other` Function with its `requirements.txt` file, this command is executed at the root of the project and repo :**

```bash
gcloud functions deploy saving-job-failures-bq_other \
  --gen2 \
  --region=europe-west1 \
  --runtime=python310 \
  --source=functions/saving_job_failures_bq_other \
  --entry-point=save_gcs_file_to_bq_function_other \
  --run-service-account=your-sa-email \
  --trigger-event-filters="type=google.cloud.storage.object.v1.finalized" \
  --trigger-event-filters="bucket=event-arc-trigger-function" \
  --trigger-location=europe-west1 \
  --trigger-service-account=your-sa-trigger-email
```

It is easy then to automate this process with a `CI CD` tool like `Cloud Build` from a single `Github` repository containing multiple Cloud Functions.

You can also check this [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/event-driven-cloud-function-load-gcs-file-to-bigquery-with-event-arc-a1540c1d2055) I written that shows an example and a project from my `Github` repository.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I'm currently trying to do. There is still an issue: let's say you have a module with useful functions at cloud-function-project/foo/bar/useful.py. How can you import this module into both your CFs?

Comment: Have you thought about creating libraries in artifact registry for your shared and utils files. It's simpler to handle shared treatments between Cloud Functions with shared and private packages ?

Comment: I think that'll be my final choice. It seemed to me pretty much overkill at first, but I cant find a simpler option. Other solutions would imply Cloud Run or several repos. I wish there was just an option like `gcloud functions deploy my_func --req custom_requirements.txt`.